# Set table cell content depending on index of the cell

Tags: html, css

Wish You all beautiful day,

I´m facing a little problem with my HTML&CSS project. I´m suppose to display smiley face on chess table depending on the cell. For white cells I should display f.e. this character: ☻ and for black cells this one: ☺.
Here is my CSS "code":

```
.table {
  margin: auto;
  border: 2px solid black; 
  border-collapse: collapse;
  box-shadow: 1em 1em 0.5em #555;  
}

.table td {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
  height: 3em;
  width: 3em;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: none;
}

.table th {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid black; 
  height: 3em;
  width: 3em;
}

.table tr:nth-child(odd) th:nth-child(even), .table tr:nth-child(even) th:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: black;
} 

.table tr:nth-child(odd) th:nth-child(even):hover::after, .table tr:nth-child(even) th:nth-child(odd):hover::after {
  font-size: 2em;
  content: '☺';
}

.table tr:nth-child(odd) th:nth-child(odd):hover::after, .table tr:nth-child(even) th:nth-child(even):hover::after {
  font-size: 2em;
  content: '☻';
}

.billboard {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 500px;
  box-shadow: 1em 1em 0.5em #555;
}
```

Smiley face for white cells is displayed correctly, however when it comes to black cells nothing is displayed. I assume that it has something to do with a fact that I set background-color attribute for the black cells, but Idk how to fix it :).

Any help will be welcomed

Comment: one advice. dont use a table for a chessboard design. Use a `css-grid` instead. you can add the smiley as either background or through pseudo-elements.

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Just add `color: white;` to the black cell style.
By the way, you should probably create a similar selector for the white cell, instead of relying on the page defaults. It'll make it more stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default color (black) is applied for the content. You should add `color:white` for black background cells.

Hover over the cells now.

```css
.table {
  margin: auto;
  border: 2px solid black; 
  border-collapse: collapse;
  box-shadow: 1em 1em 0.5em #555;  
}

.table td {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
  height: 3em;
  width: 3em;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: none;
}

.table th {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid black; 
  height: 3em;
  width: 3em;
}

.table tr:nth-child(odd) th:nth-child(even), .table tr:nth-child(even) th:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: black;
} 
.table tr:nth-child(odd) th:nth-child(odd):hover::after {color: #000; content: '☺'; font-size: 2em;}

.table tr:nth-child(even) th:nth-child(odd):hover::after {
  font-size: 2em;
  content: '☺';
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot! :D

Comment: And can I ask for explanation? I would like to understand what the hell is going on here :)

Comment: The browser default color for all elements is black so you have to be more specific

Comment: So basically all I need to do is to set content color for black cells to white and display the smiley?

Comment: Yes you are right